# OQL for finding new objects only in heap dumps?

Tags: java, jhat

Does anyone know the OQL syntax for finding new objects only in a heap output? I can't find good documentation on OQL options, sun even has an [example](https://hat.dev.java.net/doc/examples/allNewInstances.html) of new-only output without sample syntax of the query that generated it.What I've done is

- Created a set of heaps with jhat
- Served them up with jmap -baseline, which marks objects not in both heaps as "new".
- browse jhat
- scratch head

Answer (score 3):

Eclipse memory analyzer is THE tool when it comes to interpreting results of a heap dump.
See [Why doesn't the -baseline option of jhat work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1279346/why-doesnt-the-baseline-option-of-jhat-work)

Answer (score 1):

At least this page has some examples: [jstack-jhat-Object-Query-Language-OQL.html](http://www.herongyang.com/Java-Tools/jstack-jhat-Object-Query-Language-OQL.html)